# How to send a HubSpot form field using data layer to google tag manager?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, hubspot, google-datalayer

I have a HubSpot form in my website where I am trying to get leads from the users. As the webpage is also connected to an active Google Ads account, I need to send the input field which holds the email to Google Tag Manager. To do so first of all, I wrote the following code in my website's `<head>` section:

```
<head>
    ...
    <script>
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

Then, I created a Data Layer variable in Google Tag Manager dashboard which looks like below:

[image]

Finally, in my HubSpot form, I added `onFormSubmitted` function which looks like below to push the variable and its value (the user's email) to Tag Manager:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript"
    src="//js-eu1.hsforms.net/forms/shell.js"></script>
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "eu1",
        portalId: "xxxxxxxx",
        formId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        onFormSubmitted: function ($form) {
            dataLayer.push({ 'var': String($form.find('input[name="email"]').val()) });
        }
    });
</script>
```

After adding these pieces of codes, when I check the **Google Ads Submit Lead Form Conversion**, I still can't see the value.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot and some interviews with Google Ads support team, I solved the issue using `sessionStorage` and JavaScript. like below:

```
<!-- index.html -->
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "eu1",
        portalId: "xxxxxxxx",
        formId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        onFormSubmitted: function($form) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("entered_email", $form.find('input[name="email"]').val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

As the HubSpot form is redirected to a "Thank You" page after submission, inside this page:

```
<!-- thanks.html -->
<span id="email_entered"></span>
<script>
    $("#email_entered").text(sessionStorage.getItem('entered_email'));
</script>
```

For more details you can refer to [How to recover a value from localStorage in JavaScript on mobile devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74136192/how-to-recover-a-value-from-localstorage-in-javascript-on-mobile-devices)