# How to recover a value from localStorage in JavaScript on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, hubspot

I am saving a value in localStorage on my first page (first.html) like below:

```
const localStorage = window.localStorage;
localStorage.setItem('entered_email', $form.find('input[name="email"]').val());
```

Then on my second page (second.html), I am trying to retrieve the value and write it inside a `span` element.

The code looks like below:

```
<span id="email_entered"></span>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#email_entered").text(localStorage.getItem('entered_email'));
        localStorage.removeItem("key");
        localStorage.clear()
    });
</script>
```

The code works pretty well on desktop and I get the entered email on the other page but when it comes to mobile devices, I get `null`.

By the way, `$form.find('input[name="email"]').val());` is related to a HubSpot form which is written on first.html and when it is submitted, redirects the user to second.html. I have written the code inside the onFormSubmitted function of the relevant HubSpot form. The complete code looks like below:

```
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "eu1",
        portalId: "xxxxxxxx",
        formId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        onFormSubmitted: function($form) {
            const localStorage = window.localStorage;
            localStorage.setItem('entered_email', $form.find('input[name="email"]').val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is there a way to solve this issue on mobile devices?

Comment: Doesn't look wrong to me. Have you debugged this on the device? I mean using XCode for iOS devices or [remote debugging for Android](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/). There could be an unrelated JavaScript error that just halts execution or something.

Comment: @PeterKrebs I check it on Android. When the redirection happens in the second page the localStorage is empty.

Comment: Okay and setting the localStorage value definitely worked on the first? Does the second have different domain?

Comment: @PeterKrebs Yes in the first one there are no issues. consider the URLs like mydomain.com/first.html and mydomain.com/second.html

Comment: I would remove calls like `localStorage.clear()` and debug if there is a problem with emptying the localStorage too eagerly. Use step-by-step debugging in the browser. Can't really say much more since I can't pinpoint the issue.

Comment: @PeterKrebs Thanks for your help, I tried the same with sessionStorage and solved my problem. Remote debugging helped a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by using `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`. And one interesting point that I noticed after **@Peter Krebs** comment, was moving the line of code which retrieves the value from `sessionStorage` outside the `$(document).ready(function () {...});`

Therefore, the final code looks like below in `first.html`:

```
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        region: "eu1",
        portalId: "xxxxxxxx",
        formId: "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        onFormSubmitted: function($form) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("entered_email", $form.find('input[name="email"]').val());
        }
    });
</script>
```

and like below in `second.html`:

```
<span id="email_entered"></span>
<script>
    $("#email_entered").text(sessionStorage.getItem('entered_email'));
</script>
```